# Disable row count of findAll() / collection resource in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'd like to prefix this with the fact that this issue is due to PostgresSQL and its [known problem](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) with row counting.

With only tens of millions of rows, a call to `localhost:8080/myObject` takes a significant amount of time to execute because of the extra call to count all rows.

Given that, is there any way to disable the count call from the base collection resource in Spring Data REST / JPA, *without* writing custom Repository implementations that use `List` / `Iterable` / `Slice` return types for the Pageable methods?

Comment: In order for paging to work, count is needed for calculating number of pages. You could use `countQuery` or `countName` for named native query (on [@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html)) so you can write a query that returns estimated row count, based on the suggestion from the link you posted.

Comment: @PredragMaric That isn't entirely true for Spring Data.  The extra count call only happens when returning a `Page` instance.  You can return any of the listed above types as well, and none of those require a call to `count(*)`.  See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types

Comment: Sorry for confusion, that is what I meant.